# How to mount nfs using automounter(autofs)

Tags: nfs, centos-6, automount

I have an nfs at 192.168.1.10:/home/vm1/Desktop/nfs and will like to mount locally to /home/vm1/Desktop/nfs-mount using automounter...need help doing do

What i did

```
$cat /etc/auto.master
/home    /etc/auto.nfs
```

$cat /etc/auto.nfs
/vm1/Desktop/nfs-bind  -fstype=nfs  192.168.1.32:/home/vm1/Desktop/nfs

Is that the correct way to do that?

after

```
$cat /etc/auto.master
/home    /etc/auto.nfs
```

$cat /etc/auto.nfs 
vm1/Desktop/nfs-bind -fstype=nfs 192.168.1.32:/home/vm1/Desktop/nfs

this is what i am getting

```
Apr 30 06:27:30 vm1 automount[1542]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
Apr 30 06:27:30 vm1 automount[1542]: key "vm1" not found in map source(s).
Apr 30 06:28:10 vm1 automount[29547]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
Apr 30 06:28:13 vm1 automount[29547]: key "vm1" not found in map source(s).
Apr 30 06:28:18 vm1 automount[29547]: lookup_read_master: lookup(nisplus): couldn't locate nis+ table auto.master
Apr 30 06:28:18 vm1 automount[29547]: key "vm1" not found in map source(s).
Apr 30 06:29:19 vm1 automount[29547]: key "vm1" not found in map source(s).
```

Comment: Can I ask why not putting it in fstab instead?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is the correct way to do it.

Try replacing vm1/Desktop/nfs-bind with vm1.
Then attempt to navigate to /home/vm1.

(Or try replacing /home with /home/vm1/Desktop/ & /vm1/Desktop/nfs-bind with nfs-bind...)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the text file `/etc/auto.fs` to reflect this

```
$cat /etc/auto.nfs

/vm1/Desktop/nfs-bind  -fstype=nfs  192.168.1.10:/home/vm1/Desktop/nfs
```

You should input the IP address of the **nfs** server and not the machine that will be mounting the *nfs* folder. Also, make sure that the **nfs** server is exporting the folder to be shared. In your **nfs** server:

```
vi /etc/exports

/home/vm1/Desktop/nfs 192.168.1.0/24
```